# How do i show image gallery on edit page with add and udpate it using jquery in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

How do i show image gallery and update it, i am using a github jquery repo, it has a drag drop image uploading jquery code without ajax. It works fine on create page, and on edit page i can't the see images just see the placeholder. How could i update the data from there?

```
    Github repo link: https://github.com/christianbayer/image-uploader
    

    **** Laravel controller ****
```

// this is to controller to update the data

```
    public function update(Request $request, Tour $tour)
        {
            $datas = $request->validate([
                'title'                 => 'required',
                'slug'                  => 'required|unique:tours',
                'price'                 => 'required',
                'discounted_price'      => 'required',
                'days'                  => 'nullable',
                'departure'             => 'nullable',
                'included'              => 'nullable',
                'excluded'              => 'nullable',
                'body'                  => 'required',
                'image'                 => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg,webp|max:2048',
                'gallery'               => 'nullable',
                'seo_title'             => 'nullable',
                'meta_description'      => 'nullable',
                'meta_keywords'         => 'nullable',
                'location_id'           => 'required',
                'published'             => 'nullable',
                'featured'              => 'nullable',
                'views'                 => 'nullable',
            ]);
    
    
            $tour                       = Tour::where('id',$tour->id)->firstOrFail();
            $tour->title                =   $request->title;
            $tour->slug                 =   $request->slug;
            $tour->user_id              =   Auth::user()->id;
            $tour->price                =   $request->price;
            $tour->discounted_price     =   $request->discounted_price;
            $tour->days                 =   $request->days;
            $tour->departure            =   $request->departure;
            $tour->included             =    $request->included;
            $tour->excluded             =    $request->excluded;
            $tour->body                 =    $request->body;
            //seo
            $tour->meta_title            =    $request->seo_title;
            $tour->meta_description     =    $request->meta_description;
            $tour->meta_keyword        =    $request->meta_keyword;
            //relation
            $tour->location_id          =    $request->location_id;
            //other
            $tour->published            =    $request->published == true ? '1': '0';
            $tour->featured             =    $request->featured == true ? '1': '0';
    
    
    
            //image
            if($request->file('image'))
            {
                $destination = 'uploads/images/tour/'.$tour->image;
                 if(File::exists($destination))
                 {
                     File::delete($destination);
                 }
    
                //create unique name of image
                $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
    
                //move image to path you wish -- it auto generate folder
                $request->image->move(public_path('uploads/images/tour/'), $imageName);
                $tour->image = $imageName;
            }
            //gallery
            if($request->hasfile('gallery'))
             {
    
                foreach($request->file('gallery') as $image)
                {
                    $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $image->move(public_path('uploads/images/gallery/'), $name);
                    $data[] = $name;
                    $tour->gallery =$data;
                }
             }
    
             $tour->save();
    
            // foreign theme lets add to pivot table
            $theme = $request->theme;
            $tour->themes()->sync($theme);
            return redirect()->route('tour.index')->with('success', 'Tour has been updated successfully!');



*****jQuery *******
// here i have injected the data into jquery

    <script>
        let preloaded = @json($tour->gallery);
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.input-images').imageUploader({
                preloaded: preloaded,
                imagesInputName: 'gallery',
                preloadedInputName: 'old',
                maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
                maxFiles: 12
            });

        });
    </script>



****** HTML ******
```

// html code which shows image preview

```
 <div class="input-field">
        <label class="active">Gallery</label>
            <div class="input-images" style="padding-top: .5rem;"></div>
    </div>
```

*** Output screenshot ****
// Here i see only image placeholder instead of real image, however the placeholder count match with database.